# Usage of connecting phrases like "because of"

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction, conjunctions

What type of connecting phrase makes my sentence clearer and more grammatically correct? 
(At the moment, I'm using *because of*.)

> It is reasonable to conclude that the negative contribution done by the adopted growing step is higher than the other defects **because of** the incidences where the entire objects were mis-classified as terrain which we cannot expect by the segmentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence is difficult to understand for a couple of reasons.

First, it's 40 words long: ideally, according to the current wisdom, 22 words is best for any sentence, especially in technical writing.

Second, the syntax and word choice are not optimal. For example, although the first 9 words are fine (*It is reasonable to conclude that the negative contribution*), the next word and a few others aren't good choices. Perhaps the sentence would be better as two sentences:

> It is reasonable to conclude that the negative contribution **of** the adopted growing step is **greater** than **that of** the other defects. **This is because entire objects were misclassified as terrain, a problem we cannot expect if we use segmentation**.

Comment: Yes. But I suspect that what OP actually means is that it is *the negative contribution*, not *the adopted growing steps* which is greater than *other defects*. Perhaps *... the negative contribution of the adopted growing steps is greater than the negative contribution of defects arising from other causes.* That's pretty horrible; but it's a legitimate sort of awkwardness, because you're dealing with "greater negatives".

Answer (score 3):

Wow, its a long sentence. If I understand it correctly, I would say

> It is reasonable to conclude that the negative contribution done by the adopted growing step is higher than the other defects **due to** the incidences where the entire objects were mis-classified as terrain which we cannot expect by the segmentation.

or possibly **due to the fact that**
The first phrase seems to be the result (stated as "to conclude") of the second phrase, so I think *due to* is appropriate.

If you simplify the sentence, its may be a bit clearer to understand

> the negative contribution is **due to** the indices

Comment: "Due to" and "because of" are synonymous here. This substitution doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The question was how to make it more clear. Anyway it is more clear to me. I wasn't trying to say this is better or different than "because of". As you say the meaning is likely the same.

Comment: @user264 The issue isn't that *due to* and *because of* are ***synonymous***. It's more that *because of* is redundant (and colloquial--or at best--informal) because ***because*** already implies *as a result of*; that's not the case for *due to* **because** the meaning of *due* changes significantly when followed by *to*. This is ***not*** the case with *because.*

Answer (score 2):

Although it appears that this question has been long resolved, there's actually quite a lot going on here (i.e. especially for such tiny question)--surprisingly lots!--so I'd like to outline everything involved so that, should anyone else have a similar issue, it'll be here for reference purposes.

I'll start with an edited down and more precise version of your original text:

> <del>It is reasonable to conclude that</del> **The negative
>   contribution** <del>done</del> **observed during the adopted growing
>   phase** <del>is</del> **was higher than it** <del>is</del> **was overall 
>   in the others** <del>defects</del> **because there were** <del>of incidences
>   where the</del> **instances within that group (i.e., the adapted growing phase) for which entire objects were
>   mis-classified as terrain**. **, which** <del>we</del> **is
>   not** (***-or-* cannot, should not be**, etc.) **expected by** (***-or-* accounted for by, allowed
>   for by, permitted by, observed in, explained by**, etc.) the segmentation
>   [***alone/itself?***]**

**(*If I've correctly interpreted the meaning of this final, relative clause, then it should read more like this; if I'm not correct, you should consider removing it entirely because its meaning is unclear as it's written)*.

1. The primary problem with your excerpt is that **it's far too
   verbose**. I believe that, in trying to make your writing appear
   more formal and technical (which ***in and of itself*** would be fine/desirable), **you've instead, in actuality, ended up sacrificing precision
   for the sake of that formality. It is entirely possible to have both**.
2. First, to **directly** answer your question, I would ***not*** recommend using
   *because **of*** in a formal or technical paper. It is, at best, redundant. *Merriam-Webster* **does** indicate that [*because
   of*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/because+of?show=0&t=1387146538)
   is standard, but that does **not** necessarily mean that it's appropriate
   for your **technical writing** (i.e., you've got to be sure that you're **writing *for the appropriate*** audience).

   *And* second, **because this is**, *in fact*, **technical writing, *and* because**, *as a
   result,* **you'd want it** to be ***as concise/precise*** as possible, I'd
   recommend using ***only* as many words** as you *actually **need to
   unambiguously convey** your meaning*. I'd also ***avoid overly complex
   constructions, when***, *in fact*, ***you can* express the same thoughts *both*
   very simply *and* directly**.

   Also, if you look at the definition of
   [*because*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/because), on
   its own, you'll see that
   [*it's*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/because) defined as ***for the reason* that/of**, thus making the
   repetition of the word *of* completely unnecessary.

   It would sound more formal without *of*; and since your sentence is
   already on the long side, I'd suggest you omit it.

   And while M-W does list *because of* as first appearing in the 14th
   century, a quick [Ngram
   search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=because%2Cbecause+of&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbecause%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbecause%20of%3B%2Cc0)
   reveals that from 1500-Present, *because* has been by far more
   common than *because **of*** since the mid-to-late 16th century.

   Even if I adjust the time to [*from
   1900-Present*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=because%2Cbecause+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbecause%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbecause%20of%3B%2Cc0),
   it still shows *because* as being nearly three times as frequent.
   *Because of* has been increasing in frequency, but so too has *because* overall.
3. ***POV:*** I ***personally dislike formal/technical papers written in the first
   person***, so I'd remove *we* as the subject of the final clause (you might be able to remove that last clause altogether). ***If***, however, ***you'd prefer to write in the 1st rather
   than the 3rd person*, you can**; you'd just need to rephrase it as
   *which/that we wouldn't ordinarily **expect.*** It's far more important to keep your POV consistent throughout the entire body.
4. Also, you have a very, very, brief ***tense shift*** taking place in your example. You switch back-and-forth--*almost unnoticed*--between the present and the past. 
   You'll need to decide which tense is more appropriate to use and
   stick with it throughout your paper. It is--in the right
   context--fine switch tenses, but I wouldn't in this example.
5. The [*expletive
   construction*](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/572/04/) that you've used in your first sentence uses is more problematic, though.
   [*Expletive
   sentences*](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/box-expletives.html)--which usually consist of [*existential clauses*](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAnExistentialClause.htm)--are constructed in the following format/order:

   > **[Expletive](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/572/) [*pronoun (i.e., dummy
   >   pronoun)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun)** [(i.e., **it,
   >   there, who/whom[ever], that**,
   >   etc.](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/572/) **serving
   >   *solely* as a placeholder in the first word of the clause**) + **[conjugated form of *to be*]** + **subject** + **object(s)**--in precisely that order--**rather than the typical, active-voice,
   >   English
   >   construction of Subject-Verb-Object (S-V-O)**.

   Expletive sentences are existential in that they simply point to the
   existence of something, be they concepts, relationships, states of
   being, etc. Think of them as sentences that begin with giant arrows.
   The expletive is simply a pointing device of sorts.

   While it is OK to use that construction in formal writing, you
   should be careful how you use it. I think you can express this
   thought more directly in active voice instead. If it's possible to construct the sentence easily and straightforwardly without the expletive pronoun or existential clause, it's probably best to do so.
6. A quick word on *which* versus *that*: when you're using a relative
   pronoun: you ***should only use which*** for non-restrictive clauses
   (i.e. clauses that introduce non-essential information, ***which are
   separated by a comma, parentheses, em-dashes, etc.***). Note that,
   according to [*The Chicago Manual of Style Online*, 16th
   Ed.](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch06/ch06_sec022.html?para=),
   *which* and *that* are used interchangeably informally, because this is academic or professional, and because I'd be concerned about
   others perceiving that I'd made an error when in fact I hadn't, I'd
   avoid doing so. Per *Chicago*:

   > 6.22 Restrictive and nonrestrictive clauses—“which” versus “that”
   >
   > A relative clause is said to be restrictive if it provides information
   >   that is essential to the meaning of the sentence. Restrictive relative
   >   clauses are usually introduced by that (or who/whom/whose) and are
   >   never set off by commas from the rest of the sentence. The pronoun
   >   that may occasionally be omitted (but need not be) if the sentence is
   >   just as clear without it, as in the second example (before “I”).
   >
   > A relative clause is said to be nonrestrictive if it could be omitted
   >   without obscuring the identity of the noun to which it refers or
   >   otherwise changing the meaning of the rest of the sentence.
   >   Nonrestrictive relative clauses are usually introduced by which (or
   >   who/whom/whose) and are set off from the rest of the sentence by
   >   commas.
   >
   > Although which can be substituted for that in a restrictive clause (a
   >   common practice in British English), many writers preserve the
   >   distinction between restrictive that (with no commas) and
   >   nonrestrictive which (with commas). See also 5.220 under that; which.

   While a technical piece might be required to follow the [*APA
   Style*](http://www.apastyle.org/), *Chicago* is a great
   comprehensive, general AmE style guide nonetheless.
7. And finally, I'd like mention that **you should *limit* your use of
   prepositional phrases**. While they **can be helpful** by
   *clarifying/qualifying/quantifying* your writing, ***too many* will have
   *the opposite* effect**.

> The negative contribution done by the adopted growing step is higher
>   than the other defects because of the incidences where the entire
>   objects were mis-classified as terrain <del>which we cannot expect by
>   the segmentation</del>.

If, for example, you don't **specifically need
    to** end the above sentence in *by the segmentation*, then
    **don't**. It's ***impossible*** for me to say whether that one clause is essential to the rest of the body of your work based entirely on two sentences. I'm not even sure that I fully understand the topic based on the limited contextual information available to me.

Only include it if you need to introduce the idea that
    segmentation is a factor. Otherwise, it's superfluous.